# How to test if client side code correctly timeout API request to external server

Tags: http, go, client

Hi I have this following GoLang code snippet.

```
    func executeAuthorisationRequest(request http.Request) (*AuthorisationResponse, error) {
    var response AuthResponse
   
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10
    }
    requestResult, requestError := client.Do(&request)
    if requestError != nil {
       log.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Some error %s", request.Error()))
    }
 }
```

**The request is created here**

```
  func creatRequest(url string, body url.Values) (*http.Request, error){
    
    req,reqError := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost,url,strings.NewReader(body.Encode()))

if reqError != nil {
  //Error handle
}

req.Header.Add("Content-Type","some business logic")

return request,nil
```

}

I am trying to create a testcase that my client side code will timeout after 10 seconds if the server sided API is taking too long, how do I simulate/create a testcase like this

I do not have access to the server sided code

Any guidance will be highly appreciate please point me in right direction.

Comment: Please re-use a http.Client, they are not supposed to be single use.

Answer (score 2):

You need lib httptest
example:

```golang
func TestTimeout(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 15)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
    res, err := client.Get(ts.URL)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    res.Body.Close()}
```

Comment: Why do you have time.Sleep(time.Second * 15) just trying to understand your code before implementing?

Comment: To test the timeout specified in the client, the server must take longer to respond than the timeout.  Fifteen seconds is longer than ten seconds.

Comment: My code takes in a POST request not a GET request, how would I need to alter this code to solve that specific issue?

Comment: use `res, err := client.Post()`

Comment: or use `client.Do()`

Comment: This code here takes in a URL I need to take in a req pointer/reference

Comment: see documentation https://pkg.go.dev/net/http